# Ticks misaligned in ternary plot

Tags: pgfplots, ternary-diagram

I am using `TikZ` for ternary plots and have problems with a misalignment of 
ticks after changing the axis range. An example is given below where 
`ymax` is set to `0.8` but actually seem to get a maximum value of `0.8/0.99` in 
the plot. It is however only the ticks that are in the wrong position. The 
plotted values are in the correct position as demonstrated by the x in 
the minimal working example. This misalignment is value dependent and does 
for example not happen if `ymax` is set to `0.6`. 
How can I get rid of this misalignment?

Minimal working example is given below.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepgfplotslibrary{ternary}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}

\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{ternaryaxis}[
ternary limits relative=false,
width=7.5cm,
height=7.5cm,
ymax=0.8,
]

\addplot3[only marks, mark = x]
table{
0    0.8    0
};

\end{ternaryaxis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile for me.

Comment: @dustin: I can, if I remove the empty line between `\addplot` and `table`.

Comment: Lars, welcome to the site!

Comment: I discovered the same empty line myself and removed it. It should compile now.

Comment: IMO that is a bug. Set `ternary limits relative=true` and you will see the actual values being calculated (99 % for the last one)! It seems that it likes splitting in 5 or 3 parts on each axis, but not into 4. In all case you should take ranges which are dividable by the same value. Your MWE tries fitting 5 to 4 ticks.

Comment: I also suspect this to be a bug. This MWE was made as as simple as possible to demonstrate the problem and I did not care about how the ranges matched between the axes. But thank you for your advice.

Comment: OK, @Christian Feuersänger, who edited your post last, is the guy who wrote this fantastic package. As he didn't blame me for using the word "bug", I think he will be looking at this topic. Of course you could always report such an error as well.

Comment: Ok, I will wait a little at first to see if he looks into it.

Comment: I looked into it and it might be a bug. I will need some more time to dig into the issue. Thanks for the praise @LaRiFaRi.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger, did you figure out if this was a bug? I have by the way found your package to be great for making magnificent plots just the way I want them to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug. I have fixed it in the developer version (will become part of the next stable release).

A work-around for version 1.8 (and older) is to add the switch `disabledatascaling`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\usepgfplotslibrary{ternary}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{ternaryaxis}[
ternary limits relative=false,
width=7.5cm,
height=7.5cm,
ymax=0.8,
clip=false,
disabledatascaling,
]

\addplot3[only marks, mark = x]
table{
0    0.8    0
};

\end{ternaryaxis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]